# XSLT solution for counter that remembers previous counter values

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like this xml:

```
<AnXML>

 <A1>
  <B1>
   <C1>Hello</C1>
   <C2>HelloAgain</C2>
  </B1>  
  <B2>
    <C3>Yes</C3> 
  <B2>
 </A1>

 <A2>
  <B3>
   <C4>No</C4>
  </B3>
 </A2>

</AnXML>
```

To be transformed into the following:

```
<AnXML>

 <A1 id="1">
  <B1 id="2" parent="1">
   <C1 id="3" parent="2">Hello</C1>
   <C2 id="4" parent="2">HelloAgain</C2>
  </B1>  
  <B2 id="5" parent="1">
   <C3 id="6" parent="5">Yes</C3> 
  <B2>
 </A1>

 <A2 id="7">
  <B3 id="8" parent="7">
   <C4 id="9" parent="8">No</C4>
  </B3>
 </A2>

</AnXML>
```

How can I do this with an XSLT? When I tried to use a count, I couldn't figure out on how to keep the generated count I want referenced by the child elements. Maybe I need to use something other than a count. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `xsl:number` instead of `count()`. You can also pass the "parent" as a param to keep track of it.

**XML Input** (fixed to be well-formed)

```
<AnXML>
    <A1>
        <B1>
            <C1>Hello</C1>
            <C2>HelloAgain</C2>
        </B1>
        <B2>
            <C3>Yes</C3>
        </B2>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <B3>
            <C4>No</C4>
        </B3>
    </A2>
</AnXML>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|processing-instruction()|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="parent" select="''"/>
        <xsl:variable name="id">
            <xsl:number level="any" count="*" from="/*/*[1]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="string($parent)">
                <xsl:attribute name="parent">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$parent"/>
                </xsl:attribute>                
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:with-param name="parent" select="$id"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<AnXML>
   <A1 id="1">
      <B1 id="2" parent="1">
         <C1 id="3" parent="2">Hello</C1>
         <C2 id="4" parent="2">HelloAgain</C2>
      </B1>
      <B2 id="5" parent="1">
         <C3 id="6" parent="5">Yes</C3>
      </B2>
   </A1>
   <A2 id="7">
      <B3 id="8" parent="7">
         <C4 id="9" parent="8">No</C4>
      </B3>
   </A2>
</AnXML>
```

Comment: Oops! Just noticed that text was being dropped. Had the wrong input too. :-/ Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel!

Comment: @user2382922 - You're very welcome! Thanks for accepting my answer. +1 for a great question.